# zoom to map without changing values

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am using google map API and it seems to be going very good so far but the problem i am facing now is when i have initialize the map and set the markers on map everything seems to be working fine but now when i change the zoom on some click or anything it changes the values on map i.e reinitialize the whole map.

This is the HTML code :

```
<div class="map-area" id="map-area">
        <a id="map-spinner" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary " style="    margin-left: 50%;
margin-top: 20%;">
            <span>.</span>
            <div class="loader show">
                <div class="loading-circles">
                    <div class="circle hold"></div>
                    <div class="circle first"></div>
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                <img src="{{asset('images/logo-icon.svg')}}">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

And this is the javascript when it was first initialize :

```
 var getMap = function (format) {
        var request=null;
        if(format){
            if(format == 'all'){
                request = $.ajax({
                    url:app.Config.getApiUrl() + 'get-map-count',
                    method:'POST'
                });
            }else{
                request = $.ajax({
                    url:app.Config.getApiUrl() + 'get-map-count',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{format:format}
                });
            }
        }else{
            request = $.ajax({
                url:app.Config.getApiUrl() + 'get-map-count',
                method:'POST'
            });
        }
        request.done(function (response) {
            var mapLat = 0;
            var mapLng = 0;

            if(response.count.length > 0){
                $('#empty-map-image').css('display' , 'none');
                $('#map-area').show();
                mapLat =  response.last_shared_file ? response.last_shared_file.lat : response.count[0].lat;
                mapLng =  response.last_shared_file ? response.last_shared_file.lng : response.count[0].lng;
            }else{
                  $('#empty-map-image').show();
                  $('#map-area').css('display' , 'none');
            }

            $('#map-spinner').hide();
            google.load(function (google) {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-area'), {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: {lat: parseFloat(mapLat), lng: parseFloat(mapLng)}
                });
                $.each(response.count, function (k,v) {

                    var latLng = {lat: parseFloat(v.lat), lng: parseFloat(v.lng)};

                    var icon_url = $.getSrcOfFormat(v.format.toLowerCase());

                    var icon = {
                        url: icon_url, // url
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 40), // scaled size
                        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
                        labelOrigin:new google.maps.Point(30,0)
                    };
                    var label = v.count.toString();
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map,
                        icon:icon,
                        label: label,
                        title: v.count.toString()
                    });
                    var radius = parseFloat(v.radius);
                    radius = (radius * 1000);
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        map: map,
                        radius: radius,
                        fillColor: '#7ad458',
                        strokeColor: "#4a7938",
                        strokeOpacity: .35,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillOpacity: .2
                    });
                    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
                });
            });
        }).fail(function (err) {
            $('#map-area').html('<p>Unable to load map at this time.</p>')
        });
    };
```

this is what i get afterwards :

[image]

This is what i have done so far.

```
var map = $('#map-area');
map.locationpicker("location", {latitude: 24.8647309, longitude: 67.0879642,radius:1000});
```

It removes all my markers on map and reinitialized it..

Comment: Read here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction

Comment: can u show more code?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide the HTML and JS code in full

Comment: There's not enough info in the code you've provided for us to answer the question. Please show us how you're rendering and initializing the map

Comment: I have added the code for html and javascript and also the image of what i get afterwards @ChrisHalcrow and others

Comment: It's hard to check with what you've given so far. Can you build a minimal, verifiable, complete example? Are you saying your custom markers stay in the correct positions but lose their image?

Comment: just answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52004569/549372