# jQuery Location Picker Plugin get zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins

How can I get zoom property in jQuery Location Picker Plugin? I can get map coordinates using `currentLocation.latitude` and `currentLocation.longitude`, but does any body know how to get zoom property?

```
$('#the-map').locationpicker({
location: {latitude: 46.15242437752303, longitude: 2.7470703125},
radius: 300,
onchanged: function(currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
    alert("Location changed. New location (" + currentLocation.latitude + ", " + currentLocation.longitude + ")");
}
```

when I try `currentLocation.zoom` I get undefined.

Answer (score 1):

since the plugin does not support that map-event, you'd have to bind it by yourself ...

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

  $('#map_canvas').locationpicker({
      location: {latitude: 40.7324319, longitude: -73.82480777777776},
      radius: 300
  });

  /* bind the zoom_changed event for the plugin's map handle */
  $('#map_canvas').data('locationpicker').map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    var map = $('#map_canvas').data('locationpicker').map;
    console.log('zoom level: ' + map.getZoom());
  });

});
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/Logicify/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/master/dist/locationpicker.jquery.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: that's how you set the zoom. i need to get the current zoom of the map as user changes it